# Concatenate 2 binary strings in base64 form

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, binary, base64

I have two BASE64 encoded strings and I would like to get the BASE64 encoding of the binary concatenation of the two string using just the command line.

Example:

```
> $ echo -n "\x01\x02" |base64                                                          
AQI=

> $ echo -n "\x03\x04" |base64                                                              
AwQ=

> $ echo -n "\x01\x02\x03\x04" |base64
AQIDBA==
```

So the input values to my problem would be `AQI=` and `AwQ=`, the desired output is `AQIDBA==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably easiest to decode the inputs and encode again:

```
$ echo "AQI=AwQ=" | base64 -d | base64
AQIDBA==
```

(Or just run the decoder separately for each string if reading the string past the `=` padding offends your sensibilities.)

```
$ (echo "AQI=" |base64 -d ; echo "AwQ=" |base64 -d) | base64
AQIDBA==
```

Comment: This takes advantage of a glitch in `base64`.  If won't work with other Base64 decoders / encoders (f.i. with `mimencode -u` / `mimencode`).  That's because `=` is only valid at the end of the string, as padding.

Comment: glitch or a feature? In this case it happens to do exactly what is wanted.

Comment: As I said: `AQI=AwQ=` is invalid Base64 data, I can't really see how that could be a feature.  I can however easily imagine it being a parser glitch. :) In fact I'm not convinced off hand it's going to work in all cases.  You have only tested it with a single pair of 2-byte strings, where all bytes have a zero high nibble.  At the very least you need to test more corner cases. _shrug_

Comment: @SatoKatsura, is it forbidden for a decoder to decode multiple back-to-back base64 strings, then? Calling it a glitch and assuming it's broken is quite a leap, but you're of course free to show an input it breaks with.

Answer (score 3):

With `bash`:

```
str1=$(echo -ne "\x01\x02" | base64)
str2=$(echo -ne "\x03\x04" | base64)
if [[ $str1 =~ =$ ]; then
    concat=$( { base64 -d <<<"$str1"; base64 -d <<<"$str2"; } | base64 )
else
    concat="${str1}${str2}"
fi
printf '%s\n' "$concat"
```

The point being that if `str1` doesn't end in in `=` then the Base64 form has no padding, so it can be concatenated just as it is.  Otherwise the string needs to be re-encoded.

Comment: Surely there's a way to combine padded base64 strings without decoding the whole thing. Base64 encodes chunks of data (I think 4 bytes?), and later chunks have no effect on earlier chunks. In the case that the first string contains padding, you can just decode from the second-last chunk boundary of the first string and append the decoded second string before re-encoding. If you're dealing with several MB or GB of strings this makes a big difference (in terms of processing time and buffer size). For more than 2 strings this can be done recursively.

Comment: @ATLief Yes, you only need to decode the last 4 characters in the first string, and you can also avoid decoding the second string with the use of a  suitably large translation table for 1- and 2-bits shifts.  Would that be an optimization?  Absolutely.  Would that matter in the context of the actual question above, of strings of length 2 (or at least "short enough")?  Err... ROFL.  See also: [straw man argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man).